# Почему не работает replaceFirst()?

Tags: java

```
public class StringClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String s = "abcdef";
        s.replaceFirst("bc", "rrr");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он работает, просто вы не используете его результат. Объекты класса `String` в Java неизменяемы, соответственно все методы модификации возвращают новую строку.